# is it possible to set multiple shadow using filter: drop-shadow?

Tags: css

today i am learning 'clip-path' and find that it will cut box-shadow and let it not working. after searching, i determine to use drop-shadow.

Is it possible to set multiple shadow using drop-shadow ? just like using box-shadow

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as you can see from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter), `filter: <filter-function> [<filter-function>]* | none` filter accepts one or more filter functions,
this is an example:

```
filter: drop-shadow(10px 3px 5px #000000) drop-shadow(3px 10px 2px #ff0000);
```